# Use variables to create a CSV file name and path

Tags: r, file, variables, output, rstudio

Sorry, everyone.  First time using R.  The company switched to it recently and I am trying to customize a script I was given.

The purpose of the script is to:

1. Open a CSV file
2. Filter the results by a code
3. Save the results as a new CSV file named as the code

Because of this, I have to provide the code three times and the location path twice.  I am trying to streamline this so I only need to enter the code and path once, by assigning them to variables, and then the script would use those variables for everything else.

Here's what I have so far, but I'm getting an error "Error in paste(FINAL) : object 'FINAL' not found"

```
CODE <- '1234'
LOC <- 'C:/Users/myname/Documents/Raw Files/'
FINAL <- paste0(LOC,CODE,'.csv')

RawFile <- read_csv(paste0(LOC,'Raw File MERGED_Raw.csv'))

CODEofInterest <- RawFile %>% filter(ID == CODE) 

write_csv(CODEofInterest,paste0(FINAL))
```

Comment: This code should work. Did you run `FINAL <- paste0(LOC,CODE,'.csv')`?

Comment: Yes, I did.  I ran all of the lines, but it's the last one that gives me the error:

Error in paste(FINAL) : object 'FINAL' not found

Comment: Okay, now it's working.  Sorry about that, I guess I was only running the last line and not the entire script.  User error.  But this was helpful, so thank you!

Comment: If you put your cursor on the last line and clicked "run". It only runs that line. In future, highlight what you want to run and click "run" or Ctrl + Enter. You can also check the "Environment" tab to see if objects have been loaded into your R session. Finally, the console lets you know what you have just ran. So there is no way you would miss it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Today was my first time working with it.

Answer (score 0):

It was user error, I was not running the entire script, just the last line.